# Books with a technological citizen/slave world having a tournament for citizenship and a parallel magical realm

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a book title where character lives in a futuristic world divided between citizens and slaves. Winning a tournament grants citizenship. People can pass to a tech-free magic realm where tournament ability equates to magic ability.

Comment: Please do click on the "check" sign next to the answer, so it turns green, since you did consider the answer as correct !

Answer (score 23):

If there is a intelligent unicorn that would be *Split Infinity* by [Piers Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Anthony_bibliography). This is the first book of a [series known as *The Apprentice Adept*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept).

Comment: @Keith If this is the right answer you should accept and give dmckee his just reward.

Comment: It's not just to honour dmckee, but also to improve the search results on this site. As it is now, this question shows up when searching for unanswered questions.