# Sci-fi novel where people live in domes and compete with each other in games to get better domes

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can remember that people lived in coloured domes - different colours indicated your level in society. You could advance domes by playing games against opponents. There were booths were contenders would go and be presented with a grid.

One opponent would choose the skill from the left hand side (physical or logic) and the other player chose type(?) (ball game, etc) from across the top. They then had to play the corresponding game where their choices intersected on the grid.

Comment: Any hint as to when this was published?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260285/80s-sci-fi-book-players-picked-random-game-elements-to-compete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't recall anything about coloured domes, but the novel that immediately comes to mind from the description of picking games by having the competitors each select from the choices on vertical or horizontal axis of a grid is [*Split Infinity*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1155) by Piers Anthony.

> They went to a booth and played the Grid. Stile had the numeric facet; good. He regarded that as more fundamental. He would not choose MENTAL, of course; this was not a fun challenge where he wanted a good Game, but a serious challenge where he needed to win with least risk. He did not care for the 50-50 chance that CHANCE offered. Tome was pretty fair on machine arts, such as the theremin, so that was not a good risk. So it had to be Stile's strong column, PHYSICAL.
>
> Tome chose MACHINE, of course. Immediately the subgrid showed:
>
> 1.MOTION 2. ACTION 3. OBSERVATION
>
> Nine types of machine-assisted competitive sports, ranging from cycle racing in 1A to stellar location in 3C. Stile had the letter facet of this grid, unfortunately; he could not select the machine-racing column, and knew that Tome would not. Tome would go for observation-unless he figured Stile for water. That would put them in 3B, which amounted to sonar location of sunken ships. Tome was not really sharp at that. But he was a fair hand at water-hydrant dueling, so might go for ACTION. Therefore Stile went for AIR instead.
>
> He won. It came up 1C: dueling by guns, lasers, and similar powered distance weapons. Tome was good at this, but Stile was better, and both knew it.

Comment: "*The title 'Split Infinity' makes more sense after you've read the book. Piers has two worlds which are parallel dimentions on is Proton and one is called Phaze. Proton being the futuristic planet barren outside bio-domes, and Phaze being a lush land of magic and mythical creatures.*"